# error with guard let not stopping nil values in swift

Tags: swift

I have two outlets for text fields one named titleTextField (that takes in any text) and another named totalTextField (that used decimal keyboard). in a function I am trying to locally store these with guard lets that should return when the text is nil. however it seems to slip past and call the constructor with a nil value. does someone know why this is happening and how to fix it.

code:

```
guard let title = titleTextField?.text else {return}
guard let total = totalTextField?.text else {return}
let newBudget  = Budget(title, total: Double(total)!)
newBudget.saveItem()
delegate.appendData(newBudget: newBudget)
self.removeAnimate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of string >0. 
guard total.count > 0 else return